# Should REST APIs contain the ability to dispatch email?

Tags: rest, api, front-end, backend

When building a service that uses both a back-end REST API, and (a) front-end application(s), is it proper to build into that API the ability to dispatch email?

Take **Twitter** for example; for those who don't know, they function with a back-end REST API and a front-end static website that consumes JSON resources.

I don't know their internals, so I really don't know how to handle this situation for myself, however obviously they do allow users to sign up, register, recover their passwords, confirm their accounts, et cetera. Most of these things require an email to be dispatched to the user. Does the API do that, or how is this implemented?

Comment: It's implemented by code in the Twitter Server.  What are you asking, exactly?  If all a REST API could do is update records in some database, it wouldn't be very interesting.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm asking 'should' they have that ability? Is it proper for them to have that ability?

Comment: Eh, I always wince when folks ask "Is this the proper way" or "Is this the correct way."  While folks like yourself spend time figuring out how to be "correct," the rest of us are getting actual work done.  Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877968.  It not only says "yes, you can," but describes in nauseating detail why it is "correct" to do so.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks for the extensive link. I apologize (I suppose?) for asking a question on a site dedicated to these types of questions :-) Have a good one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey There's got to be balance between determining the "right" way to do something and actually doing it, of course. When you're "getting actual work done" you tend to forget that you've been educated and disciplined, formally or by your own trial and error, into doing at least *some* things the "proper" way :)

Comment: ... Granted, at some point you *do* just need to "get actual work done" ... even if it's littered will irreversible mistakes.

Comment: @svidgen: The "right" way is the way that most effectively fulfills your software's functional and non-functional requirements.  The analysis that results from that simple premise should satisfy maintainability and performance concerns, while still allowing for "best practices" without becoming cargo-cult.

Comment: @RobertHarvey But again, you say that without acknowledging a lot of the *very basic* things you've learned that you now automatically and unconsciously exercise! For example, is it "right" to name all of your variables meaningless things like `v1` and `v2`?? ... Of course not! But, your functional requirements don't demand semantic variable names. It's just something any remotely experienced developer knows to do ... It's not a question of whether you try to things "rightly," it's a question of how much of your development time should be dedicated to that pursuit. And it varies by experience.

Comment: @svidgen: There's a difference between knowing a rule from experience, and blindly following a rule without understanding it just because someone else said so.  And some of these folks spend inordinate amounts of time trying to be "right" without first understanding the issues.  If you have to ask "which hammer should I use to fix this roof," then you don't know enough yet to fix the roof.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Either way you prefer to say it, it still warrants spending some time trying to do it the "right" way... It's just a question of when and how long you spend determining what's "right" before you start working with what you know.

Comment: And I only mention it, because without any additional qualification, your 2nd comment *seems to suggest* that it's better to act before you think! And I'm quite sure you didn't mean it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sure.** Why not?

When you invoke a REST service, you're transferring state. It's up to the software on both ends to determine what actions the deltas ultimately demand.

The general exception would be for the [safe methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Safe_methods) like HEAD, GET, OPTIONS and TRACE, which should *generally* produce no side effects.

And as an exception to the exception, even for the safe methods, if your API received "too many" requests or detected other suspicious requests, you'd potentially want to have a side effect like revoking access and/or dispatching an email to a security admin.

Comment: You shouldn't use PUT, either.  Which pretty much leaves POST, for what the OP wants to do.

Comment: We shouldn't use `PUT`? Says *who!?*

Answer (score 3):

At it's heart, REST is just a mapping of CRUD operations onto HTTP verbs - it's an interface to communicate with a server. I don't think there's any expectation that calling a POST action for example should be side effect free, so don't see any problem with that being the trigger for some back-end workflow including emails.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not.

On larger projects, no, from my experience, it would not be typical that whatever script or process is on the server side of the REST request would actually send email.  More often than not, it might generate information about the email, but then stick it into a database or queue for a dedicated email process to send.  This allows applications to throttle the rate of outgoing emails, as well as handle problems that come up (resend) and logging.

Mind you, along the lines of what Robert Harvey brings up in comments, what is proper or not is completely situational.  What is appropriate for Twitter is not the same as what is appropriate for a "Scarecrow and Mrs King" PHPBB Forum with 12 members.  On smaller sites, sure, the script on the server side of the REST request can do the emailing itself.  Its probably a lot simpler than creating a dedicated process to handle 3 emails a week.  But as that grows, the functionality will probably move to more dedicated processes.